# What's the meaning of "LSP" in aosp code?

Tags: android, android-source

I found many "*LSP" functions in AOSP code, Like `applyOomAdjLSP` in `OomAdjuster.java`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This abbreviation is explained in [the ActivityManagerService source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#579):

> For the naming convention of function suffixes:
>
> - LOSP:    Locked with any Of global am Service or Process lock
> - **LSP:     Locked with both of global am Service and Process lock**
> - Locked:  Locked with global am service lock alone
> - LPr:     Locked with Process lock alone

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks